# How to get a font file name?

Tags: c#, fonts

I've written this code:

```
List<string> fontNames = new List<string>();
foreach (FontFamily font in FontFamily.Families)
{
    fontNames.Add(font.Name);
}
```

to get fonts name, but lets say if you want to copy the font to another folder, how would I get the font's file name in order to do the copy operation?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using the `BaseURI` property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.baseuri.aspx

Comment: I'm using .net 2. it's not supported...

Comment: @Xeon06 seems to be some WPF functionality. Being conservative, I would assume he is refering to WinForms only.

Comment: Then upgrade your .NET version.

Comment: I'm creating a class library to use in another application.

Comment: @Xeon06 i have limitations, can't update :(

Comment: In that case I think you're better off figuring out the directory for the fonts and manually looking up a few possibilities of name.

Comment: @Xeon06 To me your suggestion seems to be quite arrogant. Upgrading a whole environment to another presentation layer would take a huge amount of time, depending on the size of the project.

Comment: There is a [similar question and some answers over at CP](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/1136326/Font-file-name-from-System-Drawing-Font-object.aspx). Maybe this helps.

Comment: @Uwe To each his own opinion I suppose. I despise people who can upgrade but don't. These people create problems for everyone in the long run. Of course the OP in this case doesn't really have a choice, but if it had been a relatively new project, my suggestion would hold.

Comment: The limitation i mentioned is that, the thirdparty application that i'm gonna import the dll doesnt support .net 3 and above. only .net 2

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to access the registry, so you could get the file name out of the Key: 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts', basically every font file is placed in C:\Windows\Fonts, unless mentioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is a C++ solution over at CP for [getting a filename from a `HFONT` GDI+ font handle](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/xfont.aspx).

You could first use the [`Font.ToHfont()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.tohfont.aspx) to get the font handle and then use the code in the mentioned CP article. Of course this would require to rewrite the C++ code to C# with some PInvoke's.